# how to use HWIOAuthBundle to get last tweet in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twitter, hwioauthbundle

I'm using Symfony2 project,
how can i use HWIOAuthBundle to get last tweet on twitter?
Or, other bundle symfony to authentication api 1.1 of twitter?
please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I guess using the HWIOAuthBundle is not the correct choice for fetching tweets over the new API. It's main purpose is to extend the security layer, so you can implement a login system using OAuthTokens.

I recommend you the [EndroidTwitterBundle](https://github.com/endroid/EndroidTwitterBundle). It's simple, easy and created for your exact use case.

Comment: hi devsheeep, i just installed EndroidTwitterBundle. but it given the error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed